# Regex captured groups inconsistent with regex success

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following regex in C#, and while it reports success and failure almost exactly as expected, the actual content of the captured groups does not seem possible given that the match is a success.  I have two different examples against the same regex and I am not certain if they are related or not.

```
Regex specialHandlerPattern = new Regex("^\\[((Regex):(.+))|((\\w+):([^:]+)(:([0-9\\.]+))?)\\]$");
Match m = specialHandlerPattern.Match("[Regex:^Aardvark_[0-2]:[0-9]+]");    
//Match m = specialHandlerPattern.Match("[InclusiveTolerance:0.123:0.457]");

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    int i = 0;
    foreach( Group g in m.Groups) {
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tGroup {0} = \"{1}\"", i++, g);
}
```

In the first case, the match is successful as expected.  However, the content of groups 1 and 3 are not correct... both of them include a terminal ']' which is specified *outside* those groups:

```
Success!

    Group 0 = "[Regex:^Aardvark_[0-2]:[0-9]+]"

    Group 1 = "Regex:^Aardvark_[0-2]:[0-9]+]"

    Group 2 = "Regex"

    Group 3 = "^Aardvark_[0-2]:[0-9]+]"

    Group 4 = ""

    Group 5 = ""

    Group 6 = ""

    Group 7 = ""

    Group 8 = ""
```

In the second case (toggle the commented line), the match is also successful as expected. However, the content of group 0 is not correct... the leading '[' is missing:

```
Success!

    Group 0 = "InclusiveTolerance:0.123:0.457]"

    Group 1 = ""

    Group 2 = ""

    Group 3 = ""

    Group 4 = "InclusiveTolerance:0.123:0.457"

    Group 5 = "InclusiveTolerance"

    Group 6 = "0.123"

    Group 7 = ":0.457"

    Group 8 = "0.457"
```

I don't understand how these matches can be successful and still yield these groups - particularly in the first case it seems that including the extra ']' in those groups should cause regex matching to fail and then backtrack.  Is there some peculiarity of C# regexes I'm simply not aware of?

Edit:
A telling detail, perhaps?
The following strings will (contrary to my intentions) successfully match:

```
"[Regex:^Aardvark_[0-2]:[0-9]+"
"InclusiveTolerance:0.123:0.457]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you diagnose the problem.
This is your regex, formatted and expanded.
Just a suggestion - try a regex formatting application like  [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com).
This will let you edit and test from a formatted position, then compress it for production.

```
    # DO THIS
    ^                             # Beginning of string
    \[
    (                             # (1 start)
         ( Regex )                     # (2)
         :
         ( .+ )                        # (3)
    )                             # (1 end)
 |  
    # OR,
    (                             # (4 start)
         ( \w+ )                       # (5)
         :
         ( [^:]+ )                     # (6)
         (                             # (7 start)
              :
              ( [0-9\.]+ )                  # (8)
         )?                            # (7 end)
    )                             # (4 end)
    \]
    $                             # End of string
```

Maybe you just have to move the anchors ^$ and the brackets *outside*
`"^\\[(?:((Regex):(.+))|((\\w+):([^:]+)(:([0-9\\.]+))?))\\]$"`

```
 ^                             # Beginning of string
 \[
 (?:
      # DO THIS
      (                             # (1 start)
           ( Regex )                     # (2)
           :
           ( .+ )                        # (3)
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      # OR,
      (                             # (4 start)
           ( \w+ )                       # (5)
           :
           ( [^:]+ )                     # (6)
           (                             # (7 start)
                :
                ( [0-9\.]+ )                  # (8)
           )?                            # (7 end)
      )                             # (4 end)
 )
 \]
 $                             # End of string
```

Comment: You are right, the scoping of the "|" was not as intended.  I'd like to believe that this is because it was implemented differently in DXL where I learned regexes, but thinking back on it I'm becoming less certain.  (i.e. I was used to an implementation where "xa|bz" would match "xbz" but not "xa".)